# TPC-H queries. Testing and how to run them?

Tags: oracle, tpc

So I have generated the TPC-H data. Now I am trying to run its queries on the database but I can't figure out if I should use some specific values or I should somehow generate them.

For example, let's consider

```
:x
:o
select
l_returnflag,
l_linestatus,
sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
sum(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
sum(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax)) as sum_charge,
avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
count(*) as count_order

from
lineitem

where
l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' - interval ':1' day (3)

group by
l_returnflag,
l_linestatus

order by
l_returnflag,
l_linestatus;
:n-1
```

Here I don't understand what are the `:x :o :n-1` values. When I try to run this code I am asked to input the values for each of them but I don't know what I should input. Or should I just enter a `90` instead of `':1'` for example?

I am trying to do it in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an Oracle point of view.

As of this:

```
l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' - interval ':1' day (3)
```

and your question of entering some value for `:1`, yes - you should do that. For example (ran in SQL*Plus), it subtracts 90 days from sysdate (today's date):

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - interval '&1' day (3)
  3  from dual;
Enter value for 1: 90
old   2:        sysdate - interval '&1' day (3)
new   2:        sysdate - interval '90' day (3)

SYSDATE    SYSDATE-IN
---------- ----------
03.01.2021 05.10.2020

SQL>
```

---

As of other values (`x`, `o`, `n-1`) - no idea. What happens if you remove those lines?

Comment: when I run the code it throws an input dialog box where I should enter three values (for x, o, n). I tried entering some values but it doesn't work. I can run the code without those values and change the :1 part to 90 for example, and it would work just fine but I was wondering how I could use those three variables and what are they for